# Spring Data JPA persistence xml config: hibernateJpaVendorAdaptor property

Tags: xml, spring, hibernate, jpa, persistence

Am getting an error with my Spring xml config. Have tried to setup the hibernateJpaVendorAdaptor property two different ways, and both give me errors, see below. Any thoughts on how to resolve?

## First Attempt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${db.driver}"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${db.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.metagravy.ark"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">${hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.metagravy.ark.security"/>


</beans>
```

**error**

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [SpringDbContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'HibernateJpaVendorAdapter' while setting bean property 'jpaVendorAdapter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'HibernateJpaVendorAdapter' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
```

## Second Attempt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository 
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource">
        <property name="driverClass" value="${db.driver}"/>
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${db.url}"/>
        <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
        <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
    </bean>


    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- <bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/> -->

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <!-- <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/> -->
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
           <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.metagravy.ark"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">${hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <jpa:repositories base-package="com.metagravy.ark.security"/>


</beans>
```

**error**

```
Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [SpringDbContext.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#155d2eb4' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter] while setting bean property 'jpaVendorAdapter'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter#155d2eb4' defined in class path resource [SpringDbContext.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jboss/logging/Logger
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:313)
```

Comment: Check that you included the necessary logging jar in your config. For example, log4j

Comment: Yeah, did need jboss logging jars. Am still seeing a similar error though, occurs during emf initi: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.logging.Logger.getMessageLogger(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;

Comment: Possibly you messed something with the versions of libs, check what logging jar version you have, and what is required by the lib that brings you HibernateJpaVendorAdapter

Answer (score 0):

try with this file.. hope i edited everything...

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                   xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
                   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
                   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
                   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa 
                                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
                                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
                                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
                                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
                                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository 
                                       http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository.xsd">

                <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties"/>

                <bean id="dataSource" class="com.jolbox.bonecp.BoneCPDataSource">
                    <property name="driverClass" value="${db.driver}"/>
                    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="${db.url}"/>
                    <property name="username" value="${db.username}"/>
                    <property name="password" value="${db.password}"/>
                </bean>

                <!-- Activate Spring Data JPA repository support -->
                <jpa:repositories base-package="your.package.repository" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager"/>


                <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
                    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
                </bean>

                <bean id="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/> 

                <util:properties id="hibernatePropertiesProps">
                    <!--<prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop> -->
                    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">${hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>

                </util:properties>


                <tx:annotation-driven/>

                <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
                      p:persistenceProviderClass="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence"
                      p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter" 
                      p:jpaProperties-ref="hibernatePropertiesProps"
                      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource"
                      p:packagesToScan= "com.metagravy.ark" >
                    </bean>


            <!--
                <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
                    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>

                    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                        // should have been
                        <ref bean="hibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/> 
                       <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
                    </property>
                    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.metagravy.ark"/>
                    <property name="jpaProperties">
                        <props>
                            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
                            <prop key="hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy">${hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy}</prop>
                            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">${hibernate.format_sql}</prop>
                            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
                            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
                        </props>
                    </property>
                </bean>

                -->
                <jpa:repositories base-package="com.metagravy.ark.security"/>


            </beans>
```